# Slack app installation fails with "This app is requesting more permissions than what your Org Admin has granted for your organization."

Tags: slack

Once I select the channel in the app installation flow, the following error message appears.

```
This app is requesting more permissions than what your Org Admin has granted for your organization.

Please reach out to your Org Admin to request that they update this app. Learn more about why you are seeing this message.
```

I'm the admin of the workspace where I'm trying to install the app. What else am I missing?

Return uri is something like
`xyz.com/slack/oauth/callback?error=invalid_channel`

[image]

Update: Strangely, this error comes only for the first time. If I try again, installation completes successfully.

Comment: don't remember exactly what was the fix.. neither have I access to those env now to test.. sorry..